# Can I detect ctest verbosity from inside a test?

Tags: cmake, ctest, verbose, verbosity

Is it possible (via querying an environment variable, or otherwise) to detect the verbosity level that ctest is running under, from within a test?

Ie, in my test, I would like to know if "-V/--verbose" or "-VV/--extra-verbose" was passed on the command line to ctest, so I can print more information from within the test itself.

Comment: This information is not passed to the test, so you can't query it. When using make as build system, it just passes `VERBOSE=1` to makefile. It's invisible to executable.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the answer is "no", at least as far as environment variables are concerned.

I just wrote out the entire environment to a file, and diff'd the results running with "-V" and without, and there wasn't anything related to cmake's verbosity.

If anyone else knows of a clever workaround, though, I'd love to hear it!

Note - this was tested with cmake 3.13.4, with both `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)` and `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)`